# Get last week date with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the last week date in JavaScript, without the time.

So for example, `10-02-2012`, instead of `10-02-12 13:34:56 GMT`.

Is there an easy solution out there for this?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I'm trying to make this dynamic, so that the resulting variable is always one week before the current date. Here's what I've done to calculate the today variable, if this helps or can be used!

```js
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var today = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
alert(today)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I prefer something like this
    ​

```js
function getLastWeek() {
  var today = new Date();
  var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
  return lastWeek;
}

var lastWeek = getLastWeek();
var lastWeekMonth = lastWeek.getMonth() + 1;
var lastWeekDay = lastWeek.getDate();
var lastWeekYear = lastWeek.getFullYear();

var lastWeekDisplay = lastWeekMonth + "/" + lastWeekDay + "/" + lastWeekYear;
var lastWeekDisplayPadded = ("00" + lastWeekMonth.toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("00" + lastWeekDay.toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0000" + lastWeekYear.toString()).slice(-4);

console.log(lastWeekDisplay);
console.log(lastWeekDisplayPadded);
```

And if you're using jQuery UI, you can do this instead of the manual steps to build the string

```
var lastWeekDisplay = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', getLastWeek());
```

Or for today

```
var todayDisplay = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
```

Comment: This is great. How would I get the today variable also to be without the timestamp? I utilize it later in my code!

Comment: This is great -- however, whenever I alert the 'today' variable, I still get the timestamp -- is there any easy way to apply this as well? Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Nevermind, i just utilized the code I had above to. Thank you for being great!

Comment: I just realized that if the date is a single digit (say 10/4/12), then it shows up as 10/4/12, rather than 10/04/12. Is there anyway to make sure that 0 is in there?

Comment: @streetlight, if it's not zero padding, then I'm assuming you're not using the jQuery UI `$.datepicker.formatDate` method.  So you'll need to manually pad the values, I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: `let date = new Date();  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7)` Is actually the correct one

Answer (score 21):

```
 var firstDay = new Date("2009/10/02");
 var previousweek= new Date(firstDay.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Check out this link. It will help:- http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did check out date.js, but I thought it would be simpler to do it in just plain JS since I wouldn't be using all it's advanced functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

We can't have a javascript date question answered without mentioning [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
moment().subtract('days', 7).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: I have ran into this since, and moment.js has been great!

Comment: I have found this utility very useful and it is having many options like get last Sunday or next Sunday.

Answer (score 11):

Possible without external dependencies

```js
    new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create this from a full timestamp like 10-02-12 13:34:56 GMT, you might want to do this:

```
var time = '10-02-12 13:34:56 GMT';
document.write(time.substr(0,7));
```

Comment: How would I make this dynamic?

Comment: Use var time = functionToGenerateTimestamp(); And replace that function with the function you used.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to subtract any number of days as i have selected 9 it will give last 10 days result including today

```
var date = new Date();
    var day=date.getDate();
    var month=date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year=date.getFullYear();
    var startDate=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
    var dayBeforeNineDays=moment().subtract(9, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    startDate=dayBeforeNineDays;
    var endDate=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
```

Comment: Be warned that if you include Moment.
https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLastWeek() {
let today = new Date();  
let day = today.getDay();
let t = day-1;    
let monday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - t - 7); //monday from last week
let sunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - t - 1); //sunday from ast week
return [monday, sunday];
```

}
var last_week = getLastWeek();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).